# Json dropdown using codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I used given below codes to create a dependent dropdown list using data in a single table. The first client is selected. Then 2nd dropdown shows projects related to that client. when the project is selected 3rd dropdown shows the tasks related to that project. Up to here, dropdown is working. But after selecting the task, the taskcost relevant to that project does not show. I check in network console tab, But there was no error. Can somebody help me?
**Dropdown controller**

```
(defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed'));
/**
 * Class Controller
 *
 * Class Dropdown Controller to handle login & logout
 */
class Dropdown extends CI_controller
{
    /**
     * Class Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // execute parent class constructor
        parent::__construct();
        // load model
        $this->load->model('Dropdown_model');
    }

    /**
     * Default method to execute if method name missing
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $array_data = array();
        // only on Ajax Request
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            // if request for projects
            if ($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == 'project') {
                // get client name
                $client     = $this->input->post('client', true);
                // get project data by client name
                $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(trim($client), 'project');
                // AjaxPOST JSON response
                echo json_encode($array_data);die();
            }
            // if request for task
            if ($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == 'task') {
                // get project name
                $project    = $this->input->post('project', true);
                // get task data by project
                $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(trim($project), 'task');
                // AjaxPOST JSON response
                echo json_encode($array_data);die();
            }
            if ($this->input->post('action') && $this->input->post('action') == 'taskcost') {
                // get project name
                $task    = $this->input->post('task', true);
                // get task data by project
                $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(trim($task), 'taskcost');
                // AjaxPOST JSON response
                echo json_encode($array_data);die();
            }
        }
        // else get all client data
        $array_data = $this->Dropdown_model->get_dropdown_data(null, null);
        // send to view
        $this->load->view('dropdown', ['data' => $array_data]);
    }
}
```

**Dropdown_model**

```
<?php
// No direct script execution
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Class Dropdown_model to handle all related information from MySQL
 */
class Dropdown_model extends CI_Model
{
    /**
     * MySQL table which contains all data about users
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'task';
    /**
     * Returns, User First Name by Email ID
     * @param  [type] $email_addres   [description]
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function get_dropdown_data($where_data = null, $type = null)
    {
        $query = '';

        // clients only
        if (is_null($type) && is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('client_name');
            // only unique clients
            $this->db->distinct('client_name');
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }

        // projects by client
        elseif ($type == 'project' && !is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('project_name');
            // where clause
            $this->db->where('client_name', $where_data);
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }

        // task by project
        elseif ($type == 'task' && !is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('task');
            // where clause
            $this->db->where('project_name', $where_data);
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }
        elseif ($type == 'taskcost' && !is_null($where_data)) {
            // desire column from table
            $this->db->select('taskcost');
            // where clause
            $this->db->where('task', $where_data);
            // mysql table
            $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
        }

        // if record exist
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            // return all data as array
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            // error
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Dropdown view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CodeIgniter: Dependent dropdown list by using single table value</title>
    <!-- load bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- load jquery library -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- load bootstrap js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Client</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="clients" name="clients">
                <option value="0">--Select Clients--</option>
                <?php if (isset($data)):?>
                    <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value): ?>
                        <option value="<?=$value['client_name']?>"><?=$value['client_name']?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php endif ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Projects</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="projects" name="projects">
                <option value="0">--Select Projects--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Tasks</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="tasks" name="tasks">
                <option value="0">--Select Tasks--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Tasks</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="taskcost" name="taskcost">
                <option value="0">--Select Task Cost--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // client select box
            var $client     = $('select#clients');
            // project select box
            var $projects   = $('select#projects');
            // task select box
            var $tasks      = $('select#tasks');

            var $taskcost      = $('select#taskcost');
            // on change client name, get projects
            $client.on('change', function () {
                // get selected client name
                var client = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
                // post data with CSRF token
                var data = {
                    action:'project',
                    client: client,
                    "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
                };
                // AjaxPOST to get projects
                $.post('./dropdown', data, function(json) {
                    projects_data = '<option value="0">--Select Projects--</option>';
                    $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                        projects_data += '<option value="'+obj.project_name+'">'+obj.project_name+'</option>';
                    });
                    // append all projects in project dropdown
                    $projects.html(projects_data);
                }, 'JSON');
            });
            // on change project, get task
            $projects.on('change', function () {
                // get selected project name
                var project = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
                // AjaxPOSt wit CSRF
                var data = {
                    action:'task',
                    project: project,
                    "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
                };
                $.post('./dropdown', data, function(json) {
                    task_data = '<option value="0">--Select Task--</option>';
                    $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                        task_data += '<option value="'+obj.task+'">'+obj.task+'</option>';
                    });
                    // append all task data in Task dropdown
                    $tasks.html(task_data);
                }, 'JSON');
            });
            $taskcost.on('change', function () {
                // get selected taskcost 
                var taskcost = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
                // AjaxPOSt wit CSRF
                var data = {
                    action:'taskcost',
                    taskcost: taskcost,
                    "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
                };
                $.post('./dropdown', data, function(json) {
                    taskcost_data = '<option value="0">--Select TaskCost--</option>';
                    $.each(json, function(index, obj){
                        taskcost_data += '<option value="'+obj.taskcost+'">'+obj.taskcost+'</option>';
                    });
                    // append all task data in Task dropdown
                    $taskcost.html(taskcost_data);
                }, 'JSON');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Screen shot of interface
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer by myself. The view page should change as follows

```
$tasks.on('change', function () {
// get selected taskcost 
var task = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

// AjaxPOSt wit CSRF
var data = {
    action:'taskcost',
    task: task,
    "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>" : "<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>"
};

$.post('./dropdown', data, function(json) {
    taskcost = '<option value="0">--Select TaskCost--</option>';

    $.each(json, function(index, obj){
        taskcost += '<option value="'+obj.taskcost+'">'+obj.taskcost+'</option>';
    });

    // append all task data in Task dropdown
    $taskcost.html(taskcost);
}, 'JSON');
});
```